# Textviews at the end of screen in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

its a simple linear layout with 1 ImageView and 6 TextViews and a ScrollView but TextViews are appearing at the end of the screen and not below ImageView. I have tried editing my dp values in styles.xml but still not working please have a look!!
I have also tried editing my ImageView tags but still not working and don't know why TextViews are appearing at the end of the screen and if I remove ScrollView the texts are not visible.

Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="com.example.stan.sportbusinesscard.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/photo_description"

    android:src="@drawable/photo"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>

<TextView
    style="@style/TitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title" />


<TextView
    style="@style/LightText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/text1"/>
<TextView
    style="@style/TitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/where" />
<TextView
    style="@style/LightText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/address"
    android:autoLink="map"/>
<TextView
    style="@style/TitleText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/when" />
<TextView
    style="@style/LightText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/dateOf" />


 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="LightText" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#aaaaaa</item>

</style>
<style name="TitleText" parent="AppTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFD700</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce image height or Fixed ImageView Height.

Comment: try giving the image fix height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `ImageView` hight is **`wrap_content`** this the reason why your `textview` are  at the bottom of your screen

Try this set static height to your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/photo_description"    
    android:src="@drawable/photo"
    android:id="@+id/image"/>
```

Comment: @SahilShokeen happy to help u my friend

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

In your `<ImageView>` **scaleType** is `android:scaleType="fitStart"` change it to `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use  Scrollview  as parent view and add      android:adjustViewBounds="true" to Imageview for fit.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000"
   >

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/photo_description"
        android:src="@drawable/photo"
        android:id="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title" />


    <TextView
        style="@style/LightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1"/>
    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/where" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/LightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/address"
        android:autoLink="map"/>
    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/when" />
    <TextView
        style="@style/LightText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/dateOf" />


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```